# Converting functions to CPS

Tags: haskell, continuations

I have the following CPS implementation of `until`:

```
until' p f x cc = p x (\y -> if y then cc(x)
                             else until' p f (f x (\z -> cc(z))) cc)
```

Which type checks ok! Now, trying to CPS `map`:

```
map' f (x:xs) cc = f x (\y -> map f xs (\ys -> cc(y:ys)))
```

Another possible implementation:

```
map' f (x:xs) cc = cc(f x (\y cc' -> map f xs (\ys -> cc'(y:ys))))
```

However none of them type checks. Where am I doing the mistake?

```
    Couldn't match expected type ‘([a1] -> t2) -> t1’
                with actual type ‘[(a1 -> t1) -> t]’
    Relevant bindings include
      y :: a1 (bound at test.hs:6:26)
      cc :: [a1] -> t2 (bound at test.hs:6:15)
      f :: a -> (a1 -> t1) -> t (bound at test.hs:6:6)
      map' :: (a -> (a1 -> t1) -> t) -> [a] -> ([a1] -> t2) -> t
        (bound at test.hs:6:1)
    The function ‘map’ is applied to three arguments,
    but its type ‘(a -> (a1 -> t1) -> t) -> [a] -> [(a1 -> t1) -> t]’
    has only two
    In the expression: map f xs (\ ys -> cc (y : ys))
    In the second argument of ‘f’, namely
      ‘(\ y -> map f xs (\ ys -> cc (y : ys)))’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: You are calling `map` instead of `map'` in the recursive call.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the answer into your question - I got all confused at first because your first version now works...

Answer (score 4):

When rewriting in CPS the continuation takes the result, so if you write the expected type of your map function you have:

```
mapk :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> ([b] -> r) -> r
```

so the continuation takes the result list as a parameter. If you look at your implementation:

```
map' f (x:xs) cc = f x (\y -> map f xs (\ys -> cc(y:ys)))
```

`y` and `ys` should have the same type (`[b]`) however you are trying to combine them with `(:)` which expects a `b` and `[b]`. Instead you want something like:

```
mapk _ [] k = k []
mapk f (x:xs) k = mapk f xs (\rs -> k $ (f x):rs)
```

Comment: `f` presumably should be CPS converted as well, for the complete transform.

Comment: @dfeuer could you give a implementation that CPS `f` ?

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo on

```
map' f (x:xs) cc = f x (\y -> map f xs (\ys -> cc(y:ys)))
```

should be:

```
map' f (x:xs) cc = f x (\y -> map' f xs (\ys -> cc(y:ys)))
```